# Using MLE in R stats4

Tags: r, bayesian, maximum-likelihood

I have been trying to estimate the MLE for my joint posterior. I'm using R and the package stats4. I have 14 parameters and two of them are $\geq 0$, which I did not know how to implement (and I was creating NaN due to the minus log posterior required in for the mle function) and I just made it return very high value (1000) if either of the parameters were negative. Is this the right way to solve this problem? As I was forced to change my prior each time (because MLE told me that my prior estimates were way to high) and I find these nonnegative parameters going down to were low numbers (0.001 and 0.01) which did not seem right and at each iteration way below my suggested prior.

Also, since I didn't have the exact posterior due to the structure of the model and I tried to scale it such that the point estimate from the mle function plugged in the log joint posterior had the value 0. Is this approximation okay for this function?

Comment: Why are you doing MLE if you're dealing with a Bayesian problem?

Comment: I'm using block updating and in order to use that approach I need point estimate and covariance matrix to sample from and Metropolis-Hastings step to accept/reject.

Comment: What does the stats4 package do?

Comment: @smilig it's part of the standard distribution of R. I believe stats4 is a library containing statistical functions based on S4 classes (as opposed to `stats` which contains a large collection of base stats functions using the older S3 classes). It (stats4) contains a number of highly generic workhorses like plot, summary, mle and so on.

Comment: Raxel: why not reparameterize the parameters with a lower bound (say by taking logs)?

Answer (score 1):

Why use maximum likelihood for a Bayesian problem?

Nevertheless, the problem with two nonnegative parameters can be solved in several ways:

- Using a solver which admits restrictions.
- Maybe more practical, reparametrize the parameter, if it is $\theta_0 \ge 0$, represent it in the model as $\theta=\log \theta_0$. That admittedly also avoids the value zero, but it seems that's ok with you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this kind of a problem recently for computing the MLE of a triangle distribution.  I also wanted to use the `stats4` package so that users of my [triangle](https://cran.r-project.org/package=triangle) package could use the related functionality that comes with the `stats4::mle` object.  If you are interested, look [here](https://github.com/bertcarnell/triangle/blob/master/R/mle.R) and [here](https://github.com/bertcarnell/triangle/blob/master/R/mle-utils.R).

If you look at the function call for `stats4::mle`, you notice a couple of things:

```r
> stats4::mle
function (minuslogl, start, optim = stats::optim, 
          method = if (!useLim) "BFGS" else "L-BFGS-B", 
          fixed = list(), nobs, lower, upper, ...)
```

You are essentially calling the `stats::optim` function with starting parameters `start`, a function to optimize `minuslogl`, a function `optim`, a method `method`, and other parameters that are useful for control `fixed, lower, upper, ...`

So, being a little more specific than in @kjetil-b-halvorsen 's answer:

- You can use "L-BFGS-B" with lower and upper limits to accomplish your desired of some parameters being non-negative.
- You can switch our the `stats::optim` algorithm for something better like using methods in [optimx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optimx/index.html)
- You can re-parameterize your non-negative parameters in the negative log likelihood using exponentials: $f(x_1, \dots,x_{14})$ where $x_1 \ge 0$ changed to $g(z_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{14}) = f(x_1=e^{z_1}, x_2, \dots, x_{14})$
- You can just just run the optimization yourself instead of trying to fit it into `stats4::mle`.  In fact, I found it easier to troubleshoot this way.